Assigning an id to a view created inside an AndroidView Composable and access it later using findViewById
For some reason I have an app where I have to mix Views and composable :
So let's say I start with a classical Navigation Drawer Activity
first in the home_fragment.xml I add a ComposeView by adding the following code
  <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
      android:id="@+id/compose_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Then in the OnCreateView of the HomeFragment I call the composable MyComposable like this   :
val composeView = root.findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.compose_view)
        composeView.apply {
            // Dispose of the Composition when the view's LifecycleOwner
            // is destroyed
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                // In Compose world
                MaterialTheme {
                    
                    MyComposable()
                }
            }
        }  

And in my composable I will add for instance a WebView by using the AndroidView Composable and assign it a reserved name id which has been defined in Res/values/ids.xml (let call it webview_id_name) :
here is the ids.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<item name="webview_id_name" type="id"/>
</resources>

And the composable
@Composable
fun MyComposable() {

    AndroidView(
        factory = {context ->
           // LinearLayout(context)
            WebView(context)
                .apply {
                    layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                    )
                    
                    this.id= R.id.webview_id__name
                    
                    webViewClient = WebViewClient()
                    loadUrl("https://www.google.com")
                }
        },
        update = {view->
            
        }
    )

Now I would like to access to the WebView inside the HomeFragment  but whatever Fragment in the ascending lifecycle step I use, onCreateView, onViewStatedRestored, onResumed
if I defined
var view: View? = getView()
var mywebview: WebView? = view?.findViewById(R.id.webview_id_name)     

mywebview will return null.
I'm only able to catch it on descendant lifecycle at the onPause level.
What I'm doing wrong here ? How can I interact with the WebView element or whatever View created inside the composable in the fragment lifecycle ?

Did you figure out a way to do this?
